# Linker Error with Tests in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

I was following along the instructions for building tests using xcode/appcode from [TDD site](http://codingsolutions.blogspot.com/2012/12/tdd-kata-create-model-view-presenter-in.html).  I got through the initial part ok and started to experiment in my own project, but I keep getting a linking error and can't figure out where from?

The output I get is this

```
Ld /Users/prasanth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/acidplus-ctbnayjfiyhfxkccqyopjsnfagos/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/acidplusTests.octest/acidplusTests normal i386
cd /Volumes/Defiant/Freeradical/freeradical_newacidbase/acidplus
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/prasanth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/acidplus-ctbnayjfiyhfxkccqyopjsnfagos/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -LLibs/OCMock/iOS -LLibs/OCMock/iOS/OCMock -F/Users/prasanth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/acidplus-ctbnayjfiyhfxkccqyopjsnfagos/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/prasanth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/acidplus-ctbnayjfiyhfxkccqyopjsnfagos/Build/Intermediates/acidplus.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/acidplusTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/acidplusTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -force_load Libs/OCMock/iOS/libOCMock.a -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework CoreGraphics -framework SenTestingKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lOCMock -o /Users/prasanth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/acidplus-ctbnayjfiyhfxkccqyopjsnfagos/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/acidplusTests.octest/acidplusTests

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BPG_testModelObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in testModelTest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried looking at missing Sources or Linked libraries, but couldn't find anything.  Anyone know what else could be wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

Go to XCode, Under Project -> do a clean and Build your solution again.